# How to create text fields similar to Tumblr's?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create text fields that are similar to tumblr.com login and register text fields.

I launched the firebug to try to understand what is going behind the curtain but it is really behind my reach (I'm a programmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tumblr is using a Sprite for the text input treatment (I think you're talking about the glow when you mouse into the inputs?)

Check out this image:
http://www.tumblr.com/images/register_login/input.png

More on Sprites: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

What's happening is really simple.  When you mouse in, they use javascript to add a class of blurred.  This changes the background position of the image, creating the effect.  This is really simple stuff.

```
form .input_wrapper.blurred {
    background-position: left -136px;
}
```

You could just use jQuery's toggleClass to put a class on and off.  Then you can use that class to do things like they are doing (change background position of an image, change font color so preselected value is lighter, etc)

**UPDATE based on comment**

Here are steps you need to take:

Step 1 - Design images (photoshop / Aviary.com ) or download some stock ones / get a designer to design them for you.  The image you need is for the sprite.

Step 2 - Markup for form elements

Step 3 - Css for form elements (even before you add the jquery, you can use Firebug to toggle on your classes that change the position of the background elements)

Step 4 - jQuery for form elements. toggleClass / addClass / removeClass for changing the class and repositioning background.  You can either use jQuery .focus function or you can use onFocus / onBlur attributes on your form element and call some functions for clearing the text.  You can set the default text to a variable after getting it from jquery .attr selector, and then if the value is default when you mouse in, or empty, you clear it, and if it's not, you don't clear it.

I'm not gonna write the code and design the sprites for you but that's how it's done.

Comment: Wow, this is useful. What I want to achieve is to create textfields that look exactly as Tumblr's (the rounded corners, the big size and the default explanation text that gets disappeared upon gaining the focus).

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is a good tool for helping discover this.  You should be able to find this CSS:

```
.ghostwriter_input {
width: 176px;
color: #869CB2;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
border-width: 0;
background: url('/images/x.gif');
margin: 12px 0 0 11px;
padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

That is what is being used primarily, but there are other attributes as well.